# Remove highlighted indentation from sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I've been trying to set up Sublime Text with a new theme and have noticed that lines with indentation now are highlighted (see pic). Also it happens when I'm typing and indent a block.

How can I turn it off? Can't find what setting it is. It wasn't there before!

[image: Highlighted indentation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for and select 'Trailing Spaces: Toggle Trailing Spaces Highlighting' on command palette: hit ctrl+shift+p, do the search, select it and hit enter key.

Note that this procedure will only disable the highlighting; the trailing spaces will continue there. To remove them from a file you have to select 'Trailing Spaces: Delete Trailing Spaces' instead.

You can learn more at https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces

Comment: Thank you! That was really annoying me!